# Magento1.7.0.2 import customer and address programatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working with magento 1.7.0.2, I am stuck with import customer from another database (Which is not in magento) , anybody have custom script to import csv data in magento customer and address table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use default magento import customer profiler

Comment: @KeyurShah  :Thanks for your suggestion but, I am converting .net site to magento store and I need same entity Id (customer UserId) for data migration. IF I am using magento import functionality UserID will be mismatch.

Comment: It is a very very bad practice to try to map internal IDs between two systems that are alien to each other. i would rather suggest adding a custom field on magento user that will hold "old system id" so you can do mappings & transfer all customer related infos from one system to another